# Reducing straight.el Bloat

Tags: package, straight.el

TL;DR: Is there a way to have `straight.el` *not* check out a package via git repo, and have it download slim melpa packages like `package.el` does?  Also, is there a way to have it refrain from automatically downloading a lesser-used package until I manually tell it to?

I'm trying to switch to `straight.el` from `package.el` because reproducible configs and seamless integration of non-MELPA packages sound very attractive.  I've added the bootstrap code to `init.el`, added `(straight-use-package 'use-package)`, and put `:straight t` on all `use-package`s.  Unfortunately, this makes `straight.el` pull *eeeeeverything* from git repos.  This creates two problems:

1. My `~/.emacs.d` has inflated from 82MB to 2.4GB and counting.  I cannot afford this much storage on one of my  laptops, especially considering that 99% of that storage is wasted: I'm never going to hack on most of those packages!
2. The initial checkout takes forever.  When I said "and counting", I meant it's been taking about 30 minutes just to check out a *single* package, and there are a dozen more.  It's currently stuck on `mozc`, which is [a 78KB single-file elisp program living in a gargantuan C++ project](https://github.com/google/mozc/blob/master/src/unix/emacs/mozc.el).  `straight.el` is trying to pull the whole 1GB+ repo so I can get access to a long history of C++ files that won't even get compiled.

So I would like to have `straight.el` just download MELPA packages for things that are on MELPA and that I don't intend on modifying.  But writing e.g. `(straight-use-package '(mozc :source (melpa gnu-elpa-mirror))` doesn't help; `straight.el` still pulls the repo.  Seeing the [official docs' notes on backends](https://github.com/raxod502/straight.el#the-recipe-format), I'm guessing that getting packages from anywhere besides git is an unimplemented feature, but is this right?

As an additional, related goal, I'd like `straight.el` to refrain from automatically downloading every single package on startup.  For instance, I don't want `lsp-mode` installed until and unless I open a file whose major mode is set up to use `lsp-mode`.  But I can't seem to find any info on this.  Is there a way to configure packages without downloading them until there's demand?

Comment: It sounds like `straight.el` is doing exactly what it was intended to do, and your use case is not compatible with its current feature set. I think your options are to use `package.el` with MELPA stable, or (which is what I do), use `package.el` and MELPA for things where you just want the 'slim' version, and install direct from Github for the things you want more control over (with or without `straight.el`).

Comment: @Tyler Yeah, I was starting to suspect that...  That's unfortunate.  Thanks for the tip, but I think this is a dealbreaker for me.

Comment: @Jun Inoue, you are not on the right way - the ```mozc``` package (git) must be cloned on your computer and the executables must be built/installed according to the procedure suitable for your OS - see the installation documentation. The file ```mozc.el``` is the interface between Emacs and ```mozc``` application (which will be the server in this case) and it is not part of building/installing. Later must be added directly in your ```init.el``` without ```straight``` - simply add ``` (load-file "/path/to/mozc.el")  (setq default-input-method "japanese-mozc")```.

Comment: Later I can post an answer to the reducing ```straight``` bloating.

Comment: @Ian That's the thing, MELPA takes care of all that--isolating `mozc.el`, cutting down space, and making sure it appears on the path--, and AFAICT introducing `straight.el` takes away those benefits.  And for what?  I don't need or want developer access to `mozc.el`.  The insistence of `straight.el` on checking out git repos for everything just doesn't make sense, because no one is a contributor to every single package they use.  I think it can really use an option to coexist with "use-only" packages, which is what I was hoping to learn how to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must first clone and then build/install the `mozc` application. The `mozc.el` file is the interface between Emacs and your mozc application. Read the comments at the beginning of the file how to be added later.

1. To reduce the size of a git cloned package, use the command:

```sh
git clone --depth 1 your-git-source-package your-destination-folder
```

The switch `--depth` will help downloading a single commit, not the whole history.

2. The `straight` package uses the variable `straight-vc-git-default-clone-depth` by default initialized to `'full`, downloading the whole history. This may be customized in your `init.el` file, to the value `1` or even better `'(1 single-branch)`. See the code snippet below.

```lisp
;; keep this line here to shorten emacs-init-time
(setq straight-check-for-modifications '(check-on-save find-when-checking))

(defvar bootstrap-version)
(let ((bootstrap-file
       (expand-file-name "straight/repos/straight.el/bootstrap.el" user-emacs-directory))
      (bootstrap-version 5))
  (unless (file-exists-p bootstrap-file)
    (with-current-buffer
        (url-retrieve-synchronously
         "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/raxod502/straight.el/develop/install.el"
         'silent 'inhibit-cookies)
      (goto-char (point-max))
      (eval-print-last-sexp)))
  (load bootstrap-file nil 'nomessage))

(straight-use-package 'use-package)
(setq straight-use-package-by-default t)
(setq straight-vc-git-default-clone-depth '(1 single-branch))  ;; instead of the default 'full
(setq use-package-verbose nil) ;; use 't' to see execution profile at startup
```

My use case: for ~190 packages, the size of `straight` folder was reduced from 900MB to 315MB with the above settings. If such amount is still unaceptable for you, then MELPA packages...

3. As for your last goal - emacs downloads from internet all listed packages in your `init.el` file. At startup not all packages may be loaded into operating memory, some of them can be lazy-loaded - see the documentation for `use-package`.
   u

Comment: This does mitigate the problem as stated.  It's still too wasteful for my taste, but the fact that this comes up as an answer helps me to gauge what `straight.el` is or isn't meant to do.  So thank you.

Answer (score 1):

From **Emacs 29** onward, you might be interested in using package-vc.  This is a [new feature](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/etc/NEWS.29#n1725) that optionally extends package.el by providing an alternative way to fetch package sources.

The default remains to download tarballs from an ELPA server, but now you can use commands like `M-x package-vc-install` to clone a repository for a package directly.  package-vc can infer the right repositories for a number of packages, so you can do something like `M-x package-vc-install denote RET` without the need to look up where the package is developed.  If the package you want is not part of any package archive, you can also pass `package-vc-install` a URL or use the user option `package-vc-selected-packages`.  To quote an example from the manual (`(emacs) Fetching Package Sources`):

> An alternative way to use `package-vc-install' is via the` package-vc-selected-packages' user option.  This is an alist of
> packages to install, where each key is a package name and the value is
> `nil', indicating that any revision is to install, a string, indicating a specific revision or a package specification plist.  The side effect of setting the user option is to install the package, but the process can also be manually triggered using the function` package-vc-install-selected-packages'.  Here is an example of how the
> user option:
>
> ```
>  (setopt package-vc-selected-packages
>          '((modus-themes . "0f39eb3fd9") ;specific revision
>            (auctex . nil)                ;any revision
>            (foo                          ;a package specification
>             :url "https://git.sv.gnu.org/r/foo-mode.git"
>             :branch "trunk")))
> ```

The properties used in a package specification are explained in the `package-vc-install-selected-packages' documentation string.

Mixing VC packages and regular packages is no issue at all.  You can download a VC package on top of an already installed package, just for a short time to change a few things and send the changes to a maintainer (`package-vc-prepare-patch`) or create a bug report (`package-report-bug`), and then revert back to a regular package afterwards using a regular `M-x package-delete`.

Comment: Sounds very promising!  I'm still stuck with Emacs 28 and 27 for various reasons, but I'll definitely give this a try once I get to upgrade.